# Create splash ad?

Tags: 7, javascript, advertising

Drupal 7.7.

I have front_page installed and working for Anonymous users - testing it out with a ten-second expiring cookie and this:

```
<?php 
print 'Splash Ad!<br/><a href="index.php">Go to site.</a>'
?>
```

Now, I need to put an actual ad being served from OpenX.  I have the javascript code to embed this, but not sure how I go about doing it.

What would be a good way to have it open as a popup (preferably lightbox to avoid pop-up blockers) and have the ad inside?